# PHP SoapClient to call a soap method with authentication

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am trying to access a webservice (JAX-WS) with wsdl using php (5.3.5). Following is the code I am using :

```
class insoapauth 
{ 
    public $Username; 
    public $Password; 

    public function __construct($username, $pass) 
    { 
        $this->Username = $username; 
        $this->Password = $pass; 
    } 
} 
$client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.124.11:8080/cx-subscriberdata/CXSubscriberAdmin?wsdl", array( "login" => "SOAPDW", "password" => "DW@2012"));

   // Create the header 
  $auth         = new insoapauth("SOAPDW", "DW@2012"); 
  $header       = new SoapHeader("http://192.168.124.11:8080/cx-subscriberdata/CXSubscriberAdmin", "APICredentials", $auth, false); 
try {

  $result = $client->__soapCall("getDataWS", array( 
    "CrmSearchInformation" => array( 
        "searchKeyValue"        => "93700801021"        
    ) 
)); 

  echo("<br/>Returning value of __soapCall() call: ".$result);

}catch(SoapFault $exception)
{
    print_r("Got issue:<br/>") ;
  var_dump($exception);
}
```

Alternatively I tried another way using the SoapHeader and supplying it while the method call. But I am always getting the SoapFault exception :

> Could not connect to host

More details exception:

> SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in
>   C:\wamp\www\SOAPTest\client\insoaptest.php:103 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]: SoapClient->_*doRequest('*_soapCall('getDataWS',
>   Array) #2 {main}

However, using soapUI I can connect to the soapsever and can call the soapmethod with the same credentials.
Following is some example code to access the WS - I guess it's in Java- that comes with the manual:

```
INBeanService service = new INBeanService();
CXINWS wsPort = service.getCXINWSPort();
String username = "crmtestuser";
String password = "crmpassword";
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) wsPort;
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
try {
CrmSearchInformation crmSearchInfo = new CrmSearchInformation();
crmSearchInfo.setSearchKeyValue(msisdn);
CrmSearchResult result = wsPort.getDataWS(crmSearchInfo);
//handle result
System.out.println("Result state: " + result.getSearchResultState());
} catch (NxWsException e) {
// handle exceptions
}
```

Can anybody please show me some light how I can access a wsdl webservice from php with authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error before because of a cached WSDL ... try disabling the cache :

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
```

Docs on these settings [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php)